# laravel 5.4 database charset & collation for binary types

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have a requirement in my project to store images in a database, the current column type is TEXT so when trying to store an image sql throws an error about string being too long. So I created a migration

```
    Schema::table('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->binary('extras')->change();
    });
```

when I run the migration it throws an error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1253 COLLATION
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'binary' (SQL:
>   ALTER TABLE pages CHANGE extras extras B   LOB DEFAULT NULL COLLATE
>   utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

im using the default collation and charset in config.database

```
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
```

Do these not support blob formats? if not what is the correct settings for this, I have no need for unicode or emoji support.

I am using mysql v5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onlyway to do is to drop the column and use raw sql query like

```
Schema::table('portfolio', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dropColumn('image');
});

Schema::table('portfolio', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->charset = 'utf8_bin';
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `portfolio` ADD `square_image` LONGBLOB");
    DB::statement("ALTER TABLE `portfolio` ADD `portfolio_image` LONGBLOB");
});
```

Comment: Still with 5.6 being out for a while, only support for `BLOB` is there, no `LONGBLOB` or `MEDIUMBLOB` at all. Using `DB::statement()` is not portable (other database systems may not understand `LONGBLOB` or has an other equivalent). These "native queries" also defeats the purpose of having migrations which should replace such "raw SQL dumps". And dropping the column also means loosing and then recover data, no good advice again.

Comment: The only "solution" is to fill out a bug ticket (seriously here) and explain it there so they can add it, if Doctrine2 (which is being used under the hood) supports it. If not, Doctrine2 then needs to add support for it and then Laravel can include it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the LONGTEXT type:

```
$table->longText('extras');
```

My only advice woule be to decouple blob types from your table into their own since they are know for slowing down queries.

Comment: long text is still not long enough to store base64 images, it's only a persistant store for an image cache, a background job fires to warm the cache so speed is not an issue, I found the only way to do it is to drop the column and use raw sql to create longblob types

Comment: @user6858980 then consider using an other caching strategy than in database, maybe a 3-level local directory will do it?